# Tensorflow - timeseries data import with datetime

Tags: tensorflow

I am a noob for the Tensorflow and I am starting with some timeseries prediction example.

I would like to import the exact datetime instead of the sequence number for the below code. How to do that? Thanks.

Code:

```
csv_file_name = './data/sales.csv'
reader = tf.contrib.timeseries.CSVReader(csv_file_name)
train_input_fn = tf.contrib.timeseries.RandomWindowInputFn(reader, batch_size=16, window_size=42)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    data = reader.read_full()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    data = sess.run(data)
    coord.request_stop()

ar = tf.contrib.timeseries.ARRegressor(
    periodicities=100, input_window_size=35, output_window_size=7,
    num_features=1,
    loss=tf.contrib.timeseries.ARModel.NORMAL_LIKELIHOOD_LOSS)

ar.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=6000)

evaluation_input_fn = tf.contrib.timeseries.WholeDatasetInputFn(reader)
evaluation = ar.evaluate(input_fn=evaluation_input_fn, steps=1)

(predictions,) = tuple(ar.predict(
    input_fn=tf.contrib.timeseries.predict_continuation_input_fn(
        evaluation, steps=100)))
```

sales.csv

```
1,12223696.5
2,14098603
3,10515241
4,6328012
5,7200172
6,7864498
7,8036747.5
8,7537712.5
9,15359748.5
10,10074294.5
```

Error if i try to import datetime

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Field 0 in record 0 is not a valid int64: 2017-01-01
```

Comment: Are you trying to import the datetime on line 2 with `CSVReader`? It looks like only tensor dtypes are accepted (int32, float32, etc).

Comment: Yes, I don't want is order by the sequence number (1,2,3) instead of the datetime. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered converting the dates to integer time steps?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/timeseries/python/timeseries/input_pipeline.py), a `RandomWindowInputFn` accepts either a `CSVReader` or a `NumpyReader`. So you could use `pandas` to read the CSV, do the date parsing and then feed the transformed dates into a `NumpyReader`

My time-series data looks like this

```
timestamp   value
0   2014-02-14 14:30:00 0.132
1   2014-02-14 14:35:00 0.134
2   2014-02-14 14:40:00 0.134
3   2014-02-14 14:45:00 0.134
4   2014-02-14 14:50:00 0.134
```

First, i parsed the timestamp column into a `int` col using pandas

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

def date_parser(date_str):
    return dt.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%s")

data = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv"
                   , header=0
                   , parse_dates=['timestamp']
                   , date_parser=date_parser)

data['timestamp'] = data['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: int(x))
```

Then we can pass on these arrays to the `NumpyReader`

```
np_reader = tf.contrib.timeseries.NumpyReader(data={tf.contrib.timeseries.TrainEvalFeatures.TIMES: data['timestamp'].values, tf.contrib.timeseries.TrainEvalFeatures.VALUES : data['value'].values})
```

And finally pass the `np_reader` to the `RandomWindowInputFn`

```
train_input_fn = tf.contrib.timeseries.RandomWindowInputFn(
      np_reader, batch_size=32, window_size=16)
```

Hope this helps somebody!